# Expectation of uniform distribution with unknown parameter, given maximal (minimal) observation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $x_i \text{ be} ~ i.i.d. ~ \sim Uni[0,\theta]$ $(\theta \text{ unknown})$.

Denote $M_n = \max x_i$.

So, through circumferential means, I can show that $E(x_1|M_n) = \frac{n+1}{2n} M_n$. The reasoning is, if I have $n$ uniform dots on $[0,\theta]$, they (on average) divide the interval into $n+1$ equi-sized smaller intervals. Then $E(M_n)$ is the length of the first $n$ intervals, and therefore equals $\frac n{n+1} \theta$. Therefore, given $M_n,~ \theta "=" \frac{n+1}n M_n$, and $E(x_1|M_n) = \frac{\theta}2 = \frac{n+1}{2n} M_n$.

But all this reasoning strikes me as very half-formal.

Can someone help make it formal? Preferably, with some straightforward calculation, and not mathematical tricks.

Also, how should I tackle calculating $E(x_1|m_n, M_n)$, $m_n$ being the minimal value observed?

EDIT:

Given the answer below, $E(x_1|m_n, M_n)$ is

$$
E(x_1|m_n, M_n) = \frac 1nm_n + \frac 1nM_n + \left(1-\frac 2n\right) \frac{M_n+m_n}2 = \frac{M_n + m_n}{2}
$$

Comment: "But all this reasoning strikes me as very half-formal" Indeed it is. First of all, what is $x$ in $E(x|M_n)$? (There are other problems after this one as well...)

Comment: That was meant to be $x_i$ for any $i$. w.l.o.g, $x_1$. Fixed.

Comment: OK. Next problem is that your argument shows (convincingly) that $E(x_1)=\theta/2$ and $E(M_n)=n\theta/(n+1)$ hence $E(x_1)=aE(M_n)$ with $a=(n+1)/(2n)$. But you are asked a different question, which is to compute $E(x_1|M_n)$... True, $E(x_1|M_n)=aM_n$ does imply that $E(x_1)=aE(M_n)$, but not the other way around.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I see that you accepted an answer simply 10 minutes after it was posted, and that this answer does not deal with the second question in your post: computing $E(x_1|M_n,m_n)$. Surely this is because, now, you know how to solve this other question?

Comment: Yes. Following the same logic, $x_1$ is either the Max (w.p. 1/n), the min (w.p. 1/n), or uniformly distributed between the two (with the completing probability).

Comment: Right. Hence $E(x_1|M_n,m_n)=$ $____$?

Comment: Oh come on, what is this, kindergarten? I apologize, if that sounds impolite, but still. I asked the question, I understood the answer, and understood the concept behind the answer.

Comment: Perfect. If ever you go down your horse, you might want to ponder the fact that the site math.SE is *also* (some would say, mainly) meant to become a repository of clear, unambiguous, answers to math questions. In this regard, the present page is currently seriously lacking, since neither the problems with the approach in your question nor the missing parts of the accepted answer are even *mentioned* anywhere except in these comments that you seem to resent so much. Now, that YOU understood the maths is obviously positive, but hardly the only aspect of the situation which is worth mentioning.

Comment: Okay, edited. Hopefully, no arithmetical errors present.

Comment: The current formula for $E(x_1|M_n,m_n)$ is wrong.

Comment: Yes it was. Not anymore.

Comment: The new version is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that the random variable $I$ such that $X_I = M_n$ is well defined almost surely and is uniformly distributed on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Now, consider $X_1$:

- with probability $\Pr\{I = 1\} = \frac{1}{n}$, we have $X_1 = M_n$;
- with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$ we have $I \neq 1$ and $X_1$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,M_n)$.

Finally, we have
$$
E(X_1 \mid M_n) = \frac{1}{n}M_n + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{M_n}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}M_n.
$$

You can proceed similarly with the minimum, introducing $J$ such that $X_J = m_n$.